# Aligning an equation at multiple points, with both left and right alignment, as well as equals sign alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to achieve the formatting in the image attached, with the bracketed right equation/text aligned to the right side of the page. However, I would also like to be able to align the equal signs on the left hand expressions, whilst also aligning the most side of each line with the left hand side of the page.

I have attempted to do this using align and /hfill; however I suspect this is not exactly efficient or correct. I am not a Latex expert, I would just like to make lists of these fairly simple equations look pretty.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have used is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\par \vspace{3mm} R{_{1}} &= \dfrac{wl}{2} \\
\par \vspace{3mm} R{_{2}} &= R{_{1}} \\
\par \vspace{3mm} V{_{x}} &= w\left(\dfrac{l}{2}-x\right) \\
\par \vspace{3mm} V{_{max}} &= R{_{1}}=R{_{2}} \hfill \text{(at}\;R_{1}\;\text{and}\;R_{2}\text{)} \\
\par \vspace{3mm} M{_{max}}&=\dfrac{wl^{2}}{8} \hfill \text{(at centre)}\\
\par \vspace{3mm} M{_{x}}&=\dfrac{wx}{2}\left(l-x\right) \\
\par \vspace{3mm} \Delta{_{max}}&=\dfrac{5wl^{4}}{384EI} \\
\par \vspace{3mm} \Delta{_{x}}&=\dfrac{wx}{24EI}\left(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}\right) \hfill \text{(at centre)}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks and kind regards[image]

Answer (score 5):

Some preliminary notes:

- `R{_{1}}` is wrong and should be `R_{1}` (similarly for the other cases)
- “max” in a subscript should be upright
- `\par` and `\vspace` are meaningless in a math display
- the last line in a display should not end with `\\`

In the code below I used `showframe` just to show the page margins; don't use it yourself.

You can use the `eqparbox` environment. Each use should have a unique label, in this case `A`. Use a different one for each display where you need `\lefteqbox`.

I also added how I would typeset the display.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\lefteqbox}[2]{%
  \eqparbox[t]{#1}{$\displaystyle#2$\hfil}%
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

This is possibly what you want to achieve
\begin{flalign*}
\lefteqbox{A}{R_{1}}         &= \frac{wl}{2} \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{R_{2}}         &= R_{1} \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{V_{x}}         &= w\left(\frac{l}{2}-x\right) \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{V_{\max}}      &= R_{1}=R_{2}
  & \text{(at $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$)} & \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{M_{\max}}      &= \frac{wl^{2}}{8}
  & \text{(at centre)} &\\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{M_{x}}         &= \frac{wx}{2}(l-x) \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{\Delta_{\max}} &= \frac{5wl^{4}}{384EI} \\[1ex]
\lefteqbox{A}{\Delta_{x}}    &= \frac{wx}{24EI}(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}) 
  & \text{(at centre)} &
\end{flalign*}
However, my opinion is that the following is better and clearer
\begin{alignat*}{2}
R_{1}         &= \frac{wl}{2} \\[1ex]
R_{2}         &= R{_{1}} \\[1ex]
V_{x}         &= w\left(\frac{l}{2}-x\right) \\[1ex]
V_{\max}      &= R_{1}=R_{2}
  &\qquad& \text{(at $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$)} \\[1ex]
M_{\max}      &= \frac{wl^{2}}{8}
  &\qquad& \text{(at centre)} \\[1ex]
M_{x}         &= \frac{wx}{2}(l-x) \\[1ex]
\Delta_{\max} &= \frac{5wl^{4}}{384EI} \\[1ex]
\Delta_{x}    &= \frac{wx}{24EI}(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}) 
  &\qquad& \text{(at centre)}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different realization exploiting `tabular*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular*}{\displaywidth}{
  @{}
  >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}
  @{}
  >{$\displaystyle{}}l<{$}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  r
  @{}
}
R_{1}         &= \frac{wl}{2} \\[2ex]
R_{2}         &= R_{1} \\[2ex]
V_{x}         &= w\left(\frac{l}{2}-x\right) \\[2ex]
V_{\max}      &= R_{1}=R_{2}                          & (at $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$) \\[2ex]
M_{\max}      &= \frac{wl^{2}}{8}                     & (at centre) \\[2ex]
M_{x}         &= \frac{wx}{2}(l-x) \\[2ex]
\Delta_{\max} &= \frac{5wl^{4}}{384EI} \\[2ex]
\Delta_{x}    &= \frac{wx}{24EI}(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}) & (at centre)
\end{tabular*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you for your comprehensive answer. I will consider your comments too

Answer (score 1):

With the help or an `array` you can achieve the following layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}
\[
\begin{array}{llr}
 R{_{1}} &= \dfrac{wl}{2} \\
 R{_{2}} &= R{_{1}} \\
 V{_{x}} &= w\left(\dfrac{l}{2}-x\right) \\
V{_{max}} &= R{_{1}}=R{_{2}} & \text{(at}\;R_{1}\;\text{and}\;R_{2}\text{)} \\
 M{_{max}}&=\dfrac{wl^{2}}{8} & \text{(at centre)}\\
 M{_{x}}&=\dfrac{wx}{2}\left(l-x\right) \\
 \Delta{_{max}}&=\dfrac{5wl^{4}}{384EI} \\
  \Delta{_{x}}&=\dfrac{wx}{24EI}\left(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}\right) & \text{(at centre)}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: note this still has `V{_{max}}` copied from the question (wrong font and wrong `_` placement) also you could point out that you are needing `\dfrac` here as unlike the ams alignments `array` is intended for matrices of values not displayed equations so sets the entries in inline math mode.

Answer (score 1):

With `flalign*` and package `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M] {\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\eqmathbox{R{_{1}}} &= \frac{wl}{2} \\[1ex]
\eqmathbox{R{_{2}}} &= R{_{1}}\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{V{_{x}}} &= w\left(\frac{l}{2}-x\right)\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{V{_{\max}}} &= R{_{1}}=R{_{2}} & & & \text{(at}\;R_{1} \text{ and } R_{2}\text{)}\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{M{_{\max}}}&=\frac{wl^{2}}{8} & & & \text{(at centre)}\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{M{_{x}}}&=\frac{wx}{2}\left(l-x\right)\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{\Delta{_{\max}}}&=\frac{5wl^{4}}{384EI}\\[1ex]
 \eqmathbox{\Delta{_{x}}}&=\frac{wx}{24EI}\left(l^{3}-2lx^{2}+x^{3}\right) & & & \text{(at centre)}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, another great answer, thanks - there seem to be multiple ways to do this